# NPM module "deasync" not working with Hapi JS for MySQL fetch

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, hapi.js

**Current State of the Problem (After drilling down through many issues)**

So, it comes down to this. The following **independent** code [not a prt of the project] fails to function in Hapi JS while works using simple Node.

```
var Deasync = require('deasync');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000 });

var someAsyncFunction = function () {

  var connection, done, preCoins;
  console.log("fetchPreCoins called!");
  connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    database: 'db_xxx'
  });
  connection.connect();
  preCoins = null;
  done = false;
  console.log("Just before connection!");
  connection.query('SELECT preCoins from tbl_nzk_user_orbs WHERE userId = "' + "abc" + '"', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("MySQL DB Failed!");
    }
    if (!rows[0]) {
      connection.end();
      preCoins = null;
      done = true;
      console.log("Did not find");
    } else {
      connection.end();
      preCoins = rows[0].preOrbs;
      done = true;
    }
  });
  require('Deasync').loopWhile(function() {
    return !done;
  });
  console.log("fetchPreCoins about to return");
  return preOrbs;
};

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply(someAsyncFunction());
    }
});

server.start(function () {
    console.log('Started server!');
});
```

**Original Question:**
I have a queer scenario where the output code of my Coffee Script works if I put it in an independent file and run it with Node. But fails to run when it is inside a route in a restful API server written using HAPI JS.

First of all, to give an idea of the use-case; there is already a huge codebase in which this is a late addition for an extra check. I am basically out of time to refactor everything and use this in the default asynchronous way.

After some research, I am using the wonderful npm module "deasync". The following is output code on Coffee compilation, is there a configuration issue or something which prevents HAPI from making request to this external server. There is no error or anything on the terminal console, it just freezes and then times out:

```
mysql = require('mysql');
deasync = require('deasync');

fetchPreCoins = function(userId) {
  var connection, done, preCoins;
  console.log("fetchPreCoins called!");
  connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxx'
  });
  connection.connect();
  preCoins = null;
  done = false;
  console.log("Just before connection!");
  connection.query('SELECT preCoins from tbl_xxx WHERE userId = "' + userId + '"', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("MySQL DB Failed!");
    }
    if (!rows[0]) {
      connection.end();
      preCoins = null;
      done = true;
      console.log("Did not find");
    } else {
      connection.end();
      preCoins = rows[0].preCoins;
      done = true;
    }
  });
  require('deasync').loopWhile(function() {
    return !done;
  });
  console.log("fetchPreCoins about to return");
  return preCoins;
};
```

Calling it like this works perfectly in an external JS file when executed with Node:

```
fetchPreCoins();
```

The packages are properly included in the shrinkwrap and installed for my HAPI-based API server. However, the last log is "Just before connection!" which is where it gets stuck and times out. I really need this method to be synchronous or basically to wait for the response from the MySQL server and return the value.

In case of HAPI route, am just calling this like: `preCoins = Helpers.fetchPreCoins(userId)`

And I tried the same thing in the external file as:

```
value = fetchPreCoins(userId);
console.log("Value is: " + value);
```

The function returns properly. How can I make this work with Hapi JS. Is there a compatibility issue between [Node's MySQL module](http://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) and HAPI ? I had a look at [hapi-mysql](https://github.com/seldo/hapi-mysql) but I don't think that solves anything either.

Here is a subset of the HAPI route's code [CoffeeScript] which works perfectly except for when this method is called where it gets stuck.

```
method: 'POST'
path: '/sessions/users'
config:
    description: 'Create session/get token (login) for a user'
    auth: false
    validate:
        payload:
            password: Joi.string().required()
            username: Joi.string().regex(Models.usernameRegex).lowercase().trim()
    pre:
        [
                assign: 'user'
                method: (request, next) ->
                    Models.User.findOne(username: request.payload.username, '+passwordHash +passwordHashSalt').execute(next)
            ,
                (request, next) ->
                    Helpers.passwordCheck(request.payload.password, request.pre.user.passwordHashSalt, request.pre.user.passwordHash, next)
            # TODO: Could reset shared secret to improve security
        ]
    handler: (request, reply) ->
        prevDate = new Date(request.pre.user.lastSeen).setHours(0,1,0)

        if (Helpers.timeDifference(prevDate, 60) >= 24) 
            if request.pre.user.experience < 100
                addAmount = 4
            else if request.pre.user.experience >= 100 and request.pre.user.experience < 1000
                addAmount = 7
            else if request.pre.user.experience >= 1000 and request.pre.user.experience < 4000
                addAmount = 10
            else if request.pre.user.experience >= 4000 and request.pre.user.experience < 10000
                addAmount = 13
            else if request.pre.user.experience >= 10000
                addAmount = 16                      
            else
                addAmount = 3 # this should not happen though!

            if request.pre.user.membership != "free"
                addAmount += 10 # extra bonus for members

            console.log "user Id: ", request.pre.user.id    
            preCoins = Helpers.fetchPreCoins(request.pre.user.id)
            console.log "Pre coins fetched: ", preCoins
            if preCoins != null 
                if preCoins == request.pre.user.coins
                    request.pre.user.coins += addAmount
                else
                    request.pre.user.coins = preCoins + addAmount # the case when bug had occured and this reverts it   
            else        
                request.pre.user.coins += addAmount

            Helpers.writePreCoins(request.pre.user.id, request.pre.user.coins)  

            Helpers.updateNotification("continuous-day-member-coins", request.pre.user.notifications, request.pre.user)
            Helpers.updateNotification("continuous-day-coins", request.pre.user.notifications, request.pre.user)

        request.pre.user.lastSeen = Date.now()
        request.pre.user.store()
        reply(request.pre.user.toObject(transform: true))
```

**Update:**
Just to test, I stopped the "deasync" for a moment and on the HAPI API console, I get this timeout error. I can't figure out why this should happen since it is a very simple select query:

```
11:02:16 web.1  | Debug: hapi, internal, implementation, error 
11:02:16 web.1  |     Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
11:02:16 web.1  |   at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/Users/nikhilkhullar/Desktop/hapi-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:358:13)
11:02:16 web.1  |   at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
11:02:16 web.1  |   at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
11:02:16 web.1  |   at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:326:8)
11:02:16 web.1  |   at Timer.unrefTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:427:13)
```

**Update 2:**
I have found out that the actual problem is not MySQL as even writing is working when asynchronous. So, it drills down to the fact that the module [deasync](http://github.com/abbr/deasync)
CAN NOT BE used in Hapi JS. But, sadly this renders this fetch code useless. Is there a way to make this function wait for the reply now, i.e. basically to make connection.query behave synchronously.

Although, it's sad that the same "deasync" is working like a charm outside of Hapi JS...

Comment: Can you post the hapi code, or the smallest subset of it that represents how you're using this code with hapi? If the above code works, I suspect the issue is not shown in the code you've posted.

Comment: Done. Helpers is another file which is being included on top and there is no issue there as the function call does begin but never goes beyond the connection.query point...

Comment: There's nothing about hapi that precludes using the deasync module. This example works for instance: https://gist.github.com/mtharrison/de928de66d89f812f859

Comment: Also don't really understand your comment that you "don't have time to do async". How difficult is it to add a callback parameter to your function? Deasync seems like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained in more detail. Actually, I meant that if this is async, I will have to refactor quite a large chunk of the game's API/routes which is 6000+ lines i.e all the logic that follows after I call this, since that itself involves a lot of async code.

Comment: And your example sure works, then I don't get it. My MySQL code with HAPI works, although fetch is useless being async. However, as soon as I enable deasync, it only times out with the log that I posted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78853/discussion-between-nikhil-khullar-and-matt-harrison).

Comment: I think am getting closer now. I have put the simple MySQL select method in your sample code and it fails exactly like it does in my project. Any ideas .?

Comment: Sounds like you're having a problem connecting to MySQL. Try the explicit `connect()` method here: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#establishing-connections to check for any errors.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I tried to put that log in the connect method and get this now: error connecting: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/Users/nikhilkhullar/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:358:13)  ... What should I change to make this work ?

Comment: And the exact same connect succeeds outside of Hapi... I really am confused as to what is going on here ?

Answer (score 1):

As the original author of deasync I strongly recommend you (and everyone else) not to use it for anything. It's fragile and only works in some subset of cases.

It's definitely not supposed to work inside of running event loop at all: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7555#issuecomment-42295204